# How to concatenate Multiple Rows from Multiple Tables Efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation, for-xml-path

I have multiple tables with a foreign key from a main table. The tables are like this:

**Sisters**

```
MainID    IDNO   ....
111111       1   ....          
111111       1   ....          
111111       1   ....
222222       1   ....          
111111       2   ....
```

**Brothers**

```
MainID    IDNO   ....
111111     555   ....          
111111     333   ....          
111111     111   ....
222222     222   ....          
111111     321   ....
```

**Uncles**

```
MainID    IDNO   ....
111111     561   ....          
111111     121   ....          
111111     331   ....
222222     451   ....          
111111     672   ....
```

I need to concatenate all `IDNo`s in but I can't seem to get all as for example maybe I can't get 672

```
SELECT 
    ',' + S1.IDNo + ',' + B1.IDNo + ',' + U1.IDNo AS [text()] 
FROM 
    Sisters S1, Brothers B1, Uncles U1, MainTable 
WHERE 
    D1.MainID = MainTable.ID 
    AND S1.MainID = MainTable.ID 
    AND B1.MainID = MainTable.ID 
FOR XML PATH('')
```

I tried to seperate tables and concanate later but it is getting much slower that way. What can I do?

**Expected output:**

```
,1,1,1,1,2,555,333,111,222,321,561,121,331,451,672
```

Comment: FYI: maintable has around 200.000 records and the sub-tables has around 600.000 each.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s I used joins too the speed isn't effected too much

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691102/String-Aggregation-in-the-World-of-SQL-Server

Comment: Presumably, you want `union all`, but without sample results, that is only speculation.

Comment: It's not really about speed - but about **readability** and thus maintainability, and avoiding unexpected cross joins (cartesian products) ....

Comment: @jackjop please write down the expected result set that covers all scenarios (or atleast the happy path main scenario)

Comment: @obj I edited the question with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the expected output it appears that the MainID column in each of the 3 tables has no say in the output (**if so**) then this should work for you though Iam not sure it will scale to handle 600K+ records. Out of curiosity why would you want to concatenate such a large list of values ?

```
Declare @x as varchar(max) = ''

SELECT @x = @x + ',' + CAST(A.IDNO as varchar)  FROM
(
select 1 as IDNO UNION ALL
select 2 as IDNO UNION ALL
select 3 as IDNO UNION ALL
select 4 as IDNO 
) A -- Pretend this is your Sisters tables
FOR XML PATH('')
PRINT @X -- Just for Debugging Purposes

SELECT @x = @x + ',' + CAST(B.ID as varchar)  FROM
(
select 55 as IDNO UNION ALL
select 66 as IDNO UNION ALL
select 77 as IDNO UNION ALL
select 88 as IDNO 
) B -- Pretend this is your Brothers tables

PRINT @X -- Just for Debugging Purposes

SELECT @x = @x + ',' + CAST(C.IDNO as varchar)  FROM
(
select 555 as IDNO UNION ALL
select 666 as IDNO UNION ALL
select 777 as IDNO UNION ALL
select 888 as IDNO 
) C -- Pretend this is your Uncles tables


PRINT @X -- Final Output 
SELECT @X as XML_Output FOR XML PATH('')
```

**Output:**

```
,1,2,3,4
,1,2,3,4,55,66,77,88 
,1,2,3,4,55,66,77,88,555,666,777,888 -- Final Result

<XML>,1,2,3,4,55,66,77,88,555,666,777,888</XML> -- XML Output
```

So in your Case you could do something like this **(Again Not sure how it will behave on large tables)**:

```
Declare @x as varchar(max) = ''
SELECT  @x = @x + ',' + CAST(A.IDNO as varchar)  FROM
(
select MainID ,   IDNO FROM SISTERS  UNION ALL
select MainID ,   IDNO FROM BROTHERS UNION ALL
select MainID ,   IDNO FROM UNCLES
) A


SELECT @X as XML_Output FOR XML PATH('')
```

Comment: well, I want this list because the client wants to search a main item with idno's from sub-tables. though I don't know if there is an another way, the most reasonable thing that came to my mind was this. Example; if client search `555` in IDs I should display main item with ID no 111111, given the situation in my question.